# Error in request XML from 202.53.95.194 : Parsing Error : The reference to entity "F" must end with the ';' delimiter;

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I am getting this type of error `Error in request XML from 202.53.95.194 : Parsing Error : The reference to entity "F" must end with the ';' delimiter`.

Please help me how to resolve it.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FAB_BasketRQ xmlns="http://www.xmltravel.com/fab/2002/09" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Target="test" Version="2002A" xsi:type="FAB_BasketRQ">
    <SyndicatorInfo SyndicatorId="DirectTraveller" SyndicatorPassword="wrAve58w"/>
    <SessionInfo FABSessionId="ITCYB4s69vkWJVtxNmf0gGMc" CreateNewSession="false"/>
    <CreateBasketRequest ResponseTimeoutSecs="60" TargetBookingStage="confirmed_costing" ReplaceExistingBasket="true">
        <Itinerary>
            <ComponentIdentity ComponentId="1" Identity="F!RYR!economy!{F!RYR!MAN!I296e!ALC!FR!FR!4007!!!E!N!N!&F!RYR!ALC!I2GB5!MAN!FR!FR!4006!!!E!N!N!}"/>
        </Itinerary>
        <PartyInfo NumberOfAdults="2" NumberOfInfants="0" DefaultMealOkay="true"/>
        <PassengerDetails>
            <LeadCustomer Surname="adultone" Firstname="DUMMYpaxa" DOB="19851217" Title="Mr" Nationality="ZZ"/>
            <Customer Surname="adulttwo" Firstname="DUMMYpaxb" DOB="19851217" Title="Mr" Nationality="ZZ"/>
        </PassengerDetails>
    </CreateBasketRequest>
</FAB_BasketRQ>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ComponentIdentity` element have attribute `Identity` which in value contains `&` special char. It must be changed to `&amp;`.

There are 4 special chars which can't be used in the XML values:

- `<` must be changed to `&lt;`
- `>` must be changed to `&gt;`
- `&` must be changed to `&amp;`
- `"` must be changed to `&quot;`

Comment: Aside from certain prohibited ranges like control characters, the only characters that cannot appear in an xml attribute value are `<` and `&`; `>` is always perfectly safe and `'` wouldn't need to be escaped in this instance as the delimiter is `"`.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute:

```
Identity="F!RYR!economy!{F!RYR!MAN!I296e!ALC!FR!FR!4007!!!E!N!N!&F!RYR!ALC!I2GB5!MAN!FR!FR!4006!!!E!N!N!}"
```

includes `&F`. The `&` symbol has a special meaning in XML, and is used to signify a character that can't be included as-is. There are 5 characters that can't be included as they are, and need to be escaped. They are `"`, `'`, `<`, `>` and `&`.

If you want to use them in your XML, you'll need to escape them, as follows:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

So for your example, change the fragment to:

```
Identity="F!RYR!economy!{F!RYR!MAN!I296e!ALC!FR!FR!4007!!!E!N!N!&amp;F!RYR!ALC!I2GB5!MAN!FR!FR!4006!!!E!N!N!}"
```